# Rasterize vector objects in pdf

Tags: pdf, afp

Is there a server based pdf processor (like Enfocus Pitstop) capable of rasterizing the vector objects in a pack of pdfs?

Comment: Why would you want that? Don't trust the RIP of the output device?

Comment: We convert pdfs to afp in a non optimized way. The vectors bloat our afp-code.